# How to access model attributes in custom manager?

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter

I have a Django model for an object with a DateField. I also have two managers that filter these objects for a specific date range.

```
class SchoolYearManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_year = now.year
        start_date = datetime.date(current_year, 7, 1)
        end_date = datetime.date((current_year + 1), 6, 30)
        return super(SchoolYearManager, self).get_query_set().filter(status=self.model.LIVE).filter(event_date__range=(start_date, end_date))

class PastSchoolYearManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        current_year = self.model.event_date.year
        start_date = datetime.date(current_year, 7, 1)
        end_date = datetime.date((current_year + 1), 6, 30)
        return super(PastSchoolYearManager, self).get_query_set().filter(status=self.model.LIVE).filter(event_date__range=(start_date, end_date))

class Event(models.Model):
    LIVE = 3
    DRAFT = 4
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (LIVE, 'Live'),
        (DRAFT, 'Draft'),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=4, help_text="Only entries with a status of 'live' will be displayed publically.")
    event_date = models.DateField()

    objects = Models.Manager()
    school_year_events = SchoolYearManager()
    past_school_year_events = PastSchoolYearManager()
```

My first manager (SchoolYearManager) works as expected to return events within that date range. But when I try to do `Event.past_school_year_events.all()`, I get an Attribute error: "type object 'Event' has no attribute 'event_date'".

My goal with the second manager (PastSchoolYearEvents) is to wrap a generic year archive view to return events within a date range for a specific year.

Why can't I call `self.model.event_date` within the manager?

Am I going about this the right way? If not, what's the better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How could this work? What event date could it be referring to? When you call `Event.past_school_year_events.all()`, you don't have a model instance. `self.model`, as the name implies, refers to the model class. So how could it know what date you mean?

I can't actually work out what it is you're trying to do - where you are going to get the date from. Do you want to start from an event, then get all the other events in the same year as that one? In which case, I suspect you just want to make `past_school_year_events` into a model method, not a manager.

**Edit** If you want to start from a specific year, a manager certainly is appropriate, but you'll need to pass the year into your manager method as a parameter. For this, I'd use a separate method on the manager, rather than overriding `get_query_set` - in fact, add another method to `SchoolYearManager`:

```
class SchoolYearManager(models.Manager):
    def live_events(self, start_date, end_date):
       return self.filter(status=self.model.LIVE).filter(event_date__range=(start_date, end_date))

    def this_year(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_year = now.year
        start_date = datetime.date(current_year, 7, 1)
        end_date = datetime.date((current_year + 1), 6, 30)
        return self.live_events(start_date, end_date)

    def from_year(self, year):
        start_date = datetime.date(year, 7, 1)
        end_date = datetime.date(year+1, 6, 30)
        return self.live_events(start_date, end_date)
```

Now you've got just one manager, that doesn't override `get_query_set`, so you don't even need to preserve the default one - you can keep this one as `objects`. So you can do:

```
Event.objects.this_year()  # all this year's events
Event.objects.from_year(2010) # all events from 2010
```

Comment: I see your point. My goal is to take a specific year, and plug that into the start and end dates for my range filter. Then, I'd like to display those event objects using a generic year archive view. How would I do this with a method if a manager isn't appropriate?

Comment: Makes sense. So in keeping with my goal of using a generic year archive view, how would I pass in the year as an integer? For instance, this is my queryset in my view: `return Event.objects.from_year(self.get_year()).order_by('event_date')`. This returns a string, which is expected, when I need an integer.

Comment: Actually, I believe I figured that last question out. Thanks for the help!